# How can I just download assemblies from NuGet on Linux?

Tags: .net, mono, nuget

An annoying amount of open source libraries only distribute precompiled assemblies these days on Nuget. This is annoying because it's been a royal pain for me to get nuget.exe to run on my Linux box(I've been at it for over an hour)

Is there some way I can just take a NuGet URL and get a plain URL to download from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the NuGet packages using a URL if you know the NuGet package id and version.

For example you can download jQuery 2.0.3 using the URL:

https://nuget.org/api/v2/package/jQuery/2.0.3

Comment: Also, for future reference, a .nupkg file is just a ZIP file